# What is the difference between passive and past participle?

Tags: classical-latin, conjugation

Is there a semantic difference between a past participle followed by *esse* and a passive verb?

> **Example.** *Roma destructa est.* / *Roma destruitur.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is tense.
The present tense is *destruitur*, the perfect tense is *destructa est*.
Is Rome being destroyed or has it been destroyed?

Only active forms are formed from the perfect stem *destrux-*.
The corresponding passive forms (perfect, pluperfect and future perfect tenses) are formed with the passive perfect participle *desctructus* (in appropriate number and gender) and *esse*.

In the active the present (*destruit*) and perfect (*destruxit*), but in the passive the perfect group of forms looks very different.